# Single parallel process is faster than single serial process. But why? (Python multiprocessing)

Tags: python, performance, multiprocessing

I implemented a branch-and-price (bnp) method in Python 3.9.
The bnp method is implemented in a class as a serial algorithm.
To speed things up I used the multiprocessing package and created a subclass of the serial bnp class, which is able to calculate the solutions of multiple bnp-nodes in parallel. If I have multiple nodes that I can calculate at the same time, there is a performance boost (in comparison to the serial approach), which is logically explainable.
But if I only a single node is part of the problem I try to solve (no more nodes are available, and therefore no real parallel processing is possible, because there is only a single node to calculate and one process running) the performance increases anyway. This doesn't makes sense to me, because I thought it must be slower because of the overhead.

In the serial algorithm the time consuming part is implemented as "normal" method of the class and in the parallel algorithm it is implemented as a static method which is called via multiprocessing.Process() and transfers data with queues.

So the question is, how is it possible, that parallel processing is faster than serial even if only one process is run?

I run multiple tests on a Dual-Core (4-Thread) CPU and on an Hexa-Core (6 Thread) CPU. and got the same results. Run the code form VS Code Environment (debugger deactivated) and directly from Power Shell, got the same results.

I also measured the calculation time of multiple functions both implementations use and the serial approach takes longer for the same functions. This although doesn't make sense to me, because I thought that the same functions would take the same time needles if they are called from a serial or parallel process.

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing any code. I'm guessing it'll be process communication overhead anyway.

Comment: Without code, it's hard to say. But I'll take a guess! In the single node case, you're still spinning up a separate process, yes? What might be going on is that, in a separate process, the underlying C memory allocator (e.g. the one that's in GLIBC on Linux that underpins all mem allocs made by any process) is dealing with less stuff. C memory allocators these days are quite smart, asking for more than the application requests, farming out allocations from the pool it manages itself. Your separate process is less of a challenge for the C memory allocator, so maybe it guesses right more often.

Comment: The way objects are stored in memory is different in the other process. Reordering objects can result in a faster execution due to a lower memory diffusion. This can be seen by shuffling objects in a list for example. Alternatively, you should check if you do any global accesses that are local in the "parallel" processes. As said previously, we cannot really help you without the actual code, just do wild guess (and many of them can be done though only one will certainly be right). Profiling and reproducibility are the key to understand this issue.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, sadly I wasn't able to create a minimal example that reproduces the problem and the full code would be a bit much to throw at you. But thanks for the answers. That handling less objects and being able to "reorganize" them in the new process makes memory access faster sounds plausible to me.